# xcode 8 layout issue. Which constraints?

Tags: autolayout, interface-builder, constraints, xcode8

To best demonstrate see these images.

[image]

[image]

I have basic constraints but what looks ok on the larger screens does not on the smaller (images shown are 7+ and SE).

I am wanting the same look on both so which constraints are causing my issue here?
If i set a fixed height width on the image then its too big on the SE. How to have auto layout adjust these constraints in relation to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an Aspect Ratio constraint to your UIImageView and delete the bottom constraint, plus change your UIImageView content mode property to aspect fit from the attributes inspector.